# Angular PrimeNG - how to auto update number of Rows shown for TotalRecords when filtering data?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG Angular module and it shows the number of records at the bottom of the screen.

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft" let-state>
      Total rows: {{totalRecords}}
    </ng-template>
```

However that number does not change when I filter data.

How to 'auto-update' numbers?

Comment: Do you define totalRecords in your controller .ts file? If so, please share the declaration for totalRecords and how you set its value

Comment: Where does totalRecords come from? After however you're assigning the new array just do (pseudo) this.totalRecords = newArray.length + 1 and it should update the bound display text.

Comment: Only other place `totalRecords` is declared is in `questions.component.ts`:   `ngOnInit() {
    this.questionService.get().then(questions => {
      ...
      this.totalRecords = this.questions.length;
    });
}`

Comment: @danday74 - Do you have a working example with filter and totalRecords?